# Exponential backoff using azure service bus in C#

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

I am trying to implement exponential backoff with azure service bus.
Basically i have a catch block and if any error currently what i am doing is i am asking it to retry after every 1 second and i am awaiting that.

Goal :
I want to use exponential delay. So basically after each retry i want exponentially increase the seconds and i dont want it to wait. Till then it can process other messages.

Current catch block looks like :

```
catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    _logger.Error(ex, $"Failed to process request {requestId}");
                    totalAttempts++;

                    if (totalAttempts == MaxAttempts)
                        return new Response { Error = ex.ToString() };
                    
                    await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
                }
```

I tried the below but it is not exponentially increasing the time. I am using this for the first time .
while (true)

```
try
            {
                executemethod();
            }
catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    _logger.Error(ex, $"Failed to process request {requestId}");
                    totalAttempts++;

                    if (totalAttempts == MaxAttempts)
                        return new Response { Error = ex.ToString() };
                   queueClient.RetryPolicy = new RetryExponential(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30), 10);
                    
                }
```

I am not very much sure if i am doing correct.

Goal : need to retry with a back-off strategy and make the processing thread available for other messages while waiting for the next retry.Consider exponential back-off with dead-lettering after reaching max delivery attempts.

Comment: You can also use an external library like Polly

Comment: @MariusStănescu no i would like to use azure service bus as message is processed there so want to keep consistent.

Comment: so as soon as message comes to catch block i want the message to be completed and retry ot exponentially by allowing other message to process till then.

Answer (score 1):

Many Azure-oriented .NET libraries implement Retry internally. Service Bus client has it built-in as well. Check out [Retry guidance for Azure services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/best-practices/retry-service-specific#service-bus). As per documentation:

> When using the built-in RetryExponential implementation, **do not**
> **implement a fallback operation** as the policy reacts to Server Busy
> exceptions and automatically switches to an appropriate retry mode.

Other from that, you shall set policy before you make a request and not in the process.

Comment: but in my code how do i retry. I am new to this. can you guide with an example

Comment: check out the link i've posted with the answer - there is an example in it

Comment: yes i saw that but not sure what i am doing wrong. do we need try catch if we are retrying like this? so basically i want to execute the try after the exponential delay

Comment: what do you mean? a) use the example from the doc as-is b) if u need more sophisticated logic implement custom Policy class. Use try/catch for auditing/logging purposes.

Comment: when i am doing this it is executing the try part without waiting for the exponenetial delay

Comment: Retry/backoff kicks in when there was an error, not when u call it originally.

Comment: How do i get the retry count which i have defined in the policy?

Comment: where do u want to get it? and why? I mean, if it fails then it would mean the client tried to perform the request the exact number of times you set in the policy(granted the errors were transient)

Comment: Thanks i was able to get this done. Just one more thing. If i want to make a message dead lettered how do i do that?

Comment: A message must exceed MaxDeliveryCount - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-dead-letter-queues#exceeding-maxdeliverycount

Answer (score 0):

For retry policies, you can also use an external library like [Polly](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly).